# Function for each subfolder in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, subdirectory

I am new in PHP and can't figure out how to do this:

```
$link = 'http://www.domainname.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4';

$domain_and_slash = http://www.domainname.com . '/';

$address_without_site_url = str_replace($domain_and_slash, '', $link);

foreach ($folder_adress) {
// function here for example
echo $folder_adress;
}
```

**I can't figure out how to get the $folder_adress.**

In the case above I want the function to echo these four:

- folder1
- folder1/folder2
- folder1/folder2/folder3
- folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4

The $link will have different amount of subfolders...

Comment: Is this your website or? Links can be rewritten meaning there are no physical folder. If you are trying this on other sites, I suggest you leave PHP right now :)

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Webarto - Yes this is my site. Thanks to Stackoverlfow I have now created a cacheing function that will turn all my php pages into gzipped html pages. Works lite a charm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you there. Some things you might explore more: [explode](http://be.php.net/explode), [parse_url](http://be.php.net/parse_url), [trim](http://be.php.net/trim). Taking a look at the docs of there functions gets you a better understanding how to handle url's and how the code below works.

```
$link = 'http://www.domainname.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4';
$parts = parse_url($link);
$pathParts = explode('/', trim($parts['path'], '/'));

$buffer = "";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
foreach ($pathParts as $part) {
    $buffer .= $part.'/';

    echo $buffer . PHP_EOL;
}

/*
Output:

folder1/
folder1/folder2/
folder1/folder2/folder3/
folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

1) List approach: use `split` to get an array of folders, then concatenate them in a loop.

2) String approach: use `strpos` with an offset parameter which changes from 0 to 1 + last position where a slash was found, then use `substr` to extract the part of the folder string.

EDIT:

```
<?php
  $folders = 'folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4';


  function fn($folder) {
    echo $folder, "\n";
  }

  echo "\narray approach\n";
  $folder_array = split('/', $folders);
  foreach ($folder_array as $folder) {
    if ($result != '')
      $result .= '/';
    $result .= $folder;
    fn($result);
  }

  echo "\nstring approach\n";
  $pos = 0;
  while ($pos = strpos($folders, '/', $pos)) {
    fn(substr($folders, 0, $pos++));
  }
  fn($folders);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give an example from the code above?

Comment: No, by split he means split :) but yeah, explode would have been better. Haven't done PHP in a while...

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on **[explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** function

`array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )`

> Returns an array of strings, each of
>   which is a substring of string formed
>   by splitting it on boundaries formed
>   by the string delimiter.

Use **`/`** as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
$link = 'http://www.domainname.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4';
$domain_and_slash = 'http://www.domainname.com' . '/';
$address_without_site_url = str_replace($domain_and_slash, '', $link);
// this splits the string into an array
$address_without_site_url_array = explode('/', $address_without_site_url);
$folder_adress = '';
// now we loop through the array we have and append each item to the string $folder_adress
foreach ($address_without_site_url_array as $item) {
  // function here for example
  $folder_adress .= $item.'/';
  echo $folder_adress;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I had time, I could do a cleaner job. But this works and gets across come ideas: http://codepad.org/ITJVCccT

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php),  [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [array_pop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php), and [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$parts = explode("/", "folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4");
$base = "";
for($i=0;$i<count($parts);$i++){
    $base .= ($base ? "/" : "") . $parts[$i];
    echo $base . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use preg_match() for regular expression method:

```
$m = preg_match('%http://([.+?])/([.+?])/([.+?])/([.+?])/([.+?])/?%',$link)

// $m[1]: domain.ext
// $m[2]: folder1
// $m[3]: folder2
// $m[4]: folder3
// $m[5]: folder4
```

Comment: I would not. I think regular expressions is overkill here. And with your example, what if there are greater or fewer than four directories?